# PyTorch ONNX export if a submodule has extra state

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

How may I export a module with a submodule that implements `get_extra_state()` but doesn't return a tensor (returns a `dict` maybe)?
For example, when I run the following code:

```py
from typing import Any

import torch
from torch import nn


class TestModule1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Linear(10, 10)

    def get_extra_state(self) -> Any:
        return {"value1": 42, "value2": "very important"}

    def set_extra_state(self, state: Any):
        pass

    def forward(self, inputs):
        return self.layer(inputs)

class TestModule2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.test = TestModule1()
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, inputs):
        x = self.test(inputs)
        return self.relu(x)


module = TestModule2()
pretty_string = torch.onnx.export_to_pretty_string(module, torch.ones((1, 10)))
print(pretty_string)
```

it fails with the error:

```
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/onnx/__init__.py", line 388, in export_to_pretty_string
    return utils.export_to_pretty_string(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 852, in export_to_pretty_string
    graph, params_dict, torch_out = _model_to_graph(
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 727, in _model_to_graph
    graph, params, torch_out, module = _create_jit_graph(model, args)
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 602, in _create_jit_graph
    graph, torch_out = _trace_and_get_graph_from_model(model, args)
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 515, in _trace_and_get_graph_from_model
    orig_state_dict_keys = torch.jit._unique_state_dict(model).keys()
  File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/jit/_trace.py", line 71, in _unique_state_dict
    filtered_dict[k] = v.detach()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'detach'
```

I'd appreciate any ideas? Is this a bug or am I not supposed to export modules with extra states?
From the error location I would guess that this happens anytime a module with extra state is traced?

I am using python3.10 and pytorch 1.12.1.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an ideal solution, but `torch.jit` isn't actively maintained, so I doubt this will get an official solution. We can just patch the `state_dict` method of our `Module` to remove the extra state:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Dict
from unittest import mock


def remove_extra_state(func: Callable[..., Dict[str, Any]]) -> Callable[..., Dict[str, Any]]:
    def inner(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        """Remove extra state from the state dict that is not needed for ONNX export."""
        state_dict = func(*args, **kwargs)
        for extra_state_key in list(k for k in state_dict.keys() if k.endswith("_extra_state")):
            state_dict.pop(extra_state_key)
        return state_dict

    return inner


with mock.patch.object(module, "state_dict", wraps=remove_extra_state(module.state_dict)):
    pretty_string = torch.onnx.export_to_pretty_string(module, torch.ones((1, 10)))
```